# In if / then / else why would execution of res.end() forward code to final else statement?

Tags: node.js

**Node.js:** v10.16.0

**Operating System:** Windows 10

**Question:** In the following simplified test server `res.end()` kicks execution down to the final else statement no matter which route is used.  Why would that be?

**Background:**  The server below has two routes, '/' and '/users'.  If the client tries a different route 'not valid' is sent to the console.  Oddly enough 'not valid' is always sent to the console no matter what the client enters. I traced this back to the `res.end();` statement in each block.  When those are commented out this behavior doesn't occur.  I can't understand why this is happening.

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const url = req.url;
    if (url === '/') {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<header><title>/</title></header>');
        res.write('<body><h1>/</h1></body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        res.end();
    } else if (url === '/users') {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.write('<html>');
        res.write('<header><title>/users</title></header>');
        res.write('<body><h1>/users</h1></body>');
        res.write('</html>');
        res.end();
    } else {
        console.log('not valid');
    }
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Fav icon URL being fetched?

Comment: Have you tried changing your console.log at the end to be more detailed? For example, you could make it `console.log('not valid, url: ' + req.url);`

Comment: I ended up creating a sandbox for this and was not able to reproduce this. https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-bird-m63yj?fontsize=14

Comment: `console.log('not valid, url: ' + req.url);`  I updated to this line and the output is, `not valid, url: /favicon.ico`.  Super weird!  At least to me.

Comment: Then @James is correct. You need to check for `/favicon.ico`. Browsers will automatically look for this path for a favicon when they load a page.